# How could it represent a number in angular with its separation of thousands (that is to say with separation every 3 zeros)

Tags: angular

Good evening, I have the following problem in angular, I want to represent a number by separating its thousands, that is, I have the number 10000 and I want to represent it as 10.000, I tried to do it with a pipe but I only got 10,000, how could I do it?
I guess it's with PIPE but I do not know how to do it exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angulars number pipe with locale

```
{{ myNumber | number : ‘’ : ‘fr’ }}
```

Or just use the number pipe and set your locale globally:

https://angular.io/guide/i18n#setting-up-the-locale-of-your-app

Comment: Thanks for your help, I could do it by establishing my global environment